# Multiple instances of fragment with nested navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-navigation

Is there a way to have two (or more) instances of the same fragment with a navigation graph within the same app? Kind of like a "split-screen" where the user can navigate in each screen half independent of the other

[image: Multiple instances of fragment]